# 04 durango brake light not working after replacing bulb

Tags: fuse, durango

The brake light on the passenger side will not work. I've changed the bulb and checked the fuses under the hood. I'm am curious if there are separate fuses for each side or is it one fuse that both sides use. Anyhow I'm waiting for the Durango to get home to try a couple more things. So any insight on the location of the fuses would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're "just" wondering about the location of the fuse box(es)?

Comment: If it is a single light that isn't working, it is not likely the fuse. Check the bulb socket for power, corrosion, etc. I have seen these plastic housings melt and cause bulbs to not work. It is also possible you have a defective light bulb. Try swapping the bulb with the other side that is working to see if it is the bulb.

Answer (score 1):

The fuse is a likely thing to check, but only if none of the brake lights are working because there is only one fuse for both brake lights, and it's located under the hood.  It should be fuse #25* in the fuse box that is on the right side of the engine bay.

Since it's only one light, check the new bulb and make sure it's good.  Then, press on the brake pedal while someone else measures voltage to the brake light connector.  You can use a multimeter or automotive test light.  If there is voltage, then the bulb is messed up or something is wrong with the bulb holder.  If there is no voltage, there's probably a bad connection somewhere, which can get hard to find.

Fuse location if you really want to check anyway:

> [image]
>
> ```
> Fuse#  Amps  Function
>
> 25*     15A   Brake/Stop Lamps
> ```
>
> http://fusesdiagram.com/dodge/fuse-box-diagram-dodge-durango-2.html

(*) Corrected by user with service manual.

Comment: The chart for the PDC is mislabeled on that page, it should be fuse 25 15A. Confirmed against service info.